# How to manage simultaneously running functions/ feedback from function/ state engine?

Tags: python

I am running into troubles managing several functions, when they should be called or not.

I am working on a RTS Game with pygame. There is a Spaceship to control. It has several functions like: move_to_mouseposition, move_to_target and a bunch of functions called inside these functions, like calculate_travel_costs, fix_positions, blitstuff , caclulate_distance and vectors, etc.

Example:
on left_click the space ship gets selected, on right_click deselected. But also on right click it shoud call move_to_target if it has a target, else it should deselect but only if not hovering in another certain game_oject. and so on.

One can see, it gets complicated, even with one function.
I then tried with if/else statements, even with function callbacks (True or False) from the functions itself.

What is the term for this issue:

- state engine?
- decision matrix?
- KI something?

EDIT:

i have found a solution: used breakpoints from pycharm. splitted functions into smaller methods. draw everything in the overwritten draw function from pygame_widgets.widgedBase.

like this, you can see every value from every Class.. pretty amazing tool !!